# How to setup tests using builds in TFS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, automated-tests

Currently I have a setup of build controllers. I want to run automation test scripts referring to some dll. I tried giving the set-up in Process tab of build definition under automated tests. But nothing happens. Please guide what things are necessary for running automated tests.

Comment: Can you provide the items you configured in the Build Definition's Process tab?  Tests are off by default in a build definition and you need to flip them On in addition to adding the test containers/lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good guide to setting up automated unit test in TFS Builds: http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2009/06/03/tfs-team-build-2010-running-unit-tests.aspx